# Рекурсивный спуск/возврат С++

Tags: c++

Не могли бы объяснить отличие выполнение кода на рекурсивном спуске и возврате (с примером)? Как вообще определить, что программа выполняется на рек. спуске или возврате? Материала с примерами в интернете почти нет, только еще больше запутался. Можно увидеть один и тот же алгоритм, но написанный на рек. спуске и возврате? Спасибо за помощь, очень надо разобраться.

Comment: Там, где вы эти термины, как "рекурсивный спуск" вычитали, там и ищите примеры.:)

Comment: Дело в том, что такую теорию дали в универе, но вот на практике не объяснили и я не вижу различия. Поэтому прошу помощи тут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примером рекурсивного возврата может служить функция вычисляющая факторал:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fact(int x)
{
    int mult;

    if (x == 1)
        mult = 1;
    else
        mult = fact(x - 1);

    // результат вычисляется посредством рекурсивного возврата
    return mult * x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 5;
    cout << "Fact !n = " << fact(n) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Примером рекурсивного спуска может служить программа построения дерева каталогов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

list<string> get_subdirs(const string &path)
{
    // какая-то реализация получения списка каталогов, зависимая от ОС
}

string path_concat(const string &path, const string &name)
{
    // какая-то реализация склеивания пути с именем, напр.: C:\\Users + Admin = C:\\Users\\Admin
}

string indent(int level)
{
    // сформировать отступ
    string result;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < level; ++i)
        result += '-';

    return result;
}

void print_directory(const string &path, int level = 1)
{
    list<string> subdirs = get_subdirs(path);

    for (list<string>::iterator it = subdirs.begin(); it != subdirs.end(); ++it)
    {
        string dir = *it;
        cout << indent(level) << dir << endl;
        print_directory(path_concat(path, dir), level + 1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    print_directory("C:\\");
    return 0;
}
```

Код писал на коленке, корректность не гарантирую.

Comment: я правильно понял, что рек.возврат, это когда в операторе return прописано какое-то выражение? А спуск - это когда все действия выполняются до return (return вернет только готовый результат уже)?

Comment: когда готовый результат формируется через return и в стартовой точке ты его обрабатываешь - это рекурсивный возврат. Когда же ты просто сам с себя заходишь что бы что-то делать это спуск.

Comment: Вот спасибо, теперь хоть что-то прояснилось!